# Do we have any way to note, record or collect errors/problems/omissions/potential improvements to Space Exploration-related Wikipedia pages?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing Wikipedia's [Stack Exchange; Notable users; Other notable scientists and mathematicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#Other_notable_scientists_and_mathematicians) and saw at least one familiar Space SE user [Anders Sandberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Sandberg) but saw that prolific/notable [Mark Adler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Adler) was missing as was [Emily Lakdawalla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emily_Lakdawalla) seen [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24631/12102)<sup>1</sup>.

I'm not a Wikipedia editor or I'd go to the talk page and suggest that they be added.

But this touches on a broader issue, the frequency with which errors/problems/omissions/potential improvements to Space Exploration-related Wikipedia pages come up in comments or answers.

I'm wondering if a community wiki-like meta post might be a vehicle for a "to do" list of improvements.

Normally one might say "Wiki is Wiki and SE is SE, and never the twain shall meet." but really the connections between Space SE and the Space related Wikipedia pages is incredibly intimate - I would guess that a SEDE script counting links to and quotes from Wikipedia pages will turn up of order 10<sup>4</sup> separate instances.

So I am wondering:

**Question:** Do we have any way to note, record or collect errors/problems/omissions/potential improvements to Space Exploration-related Wikipedia pages? If not, sh/could we start one? Perhaps a community wiki "to do" list?

---

<sup>1</sup>oh, that's an unregistered user, so probably sub-threshold for notable user.

Comment: I can't think of anyone who has lamented errors/problems/omissions in Wikipedia pages more than @DavidHammen so your thoughts on this are of particular interest!

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the talk page and suggest that they be added.

That's what the talk pages are for.  Provide as much information as possible.

The only valid reason for not posting on the talk pages is if one has been banned from Wikipedia

If one doesn't want to post on the talk page, then they shouldn't. But that's on them; they shouldn't come to space.stackexchange and waste its users time with it.

If a user was genuinely confused, they might come to space.stackexchange, and write a question of the form "I saw this on Wikipedia, but is it correct, considering that and the other?" but they really shouldn't do that if they already know the answer.